# Primefaces components rendering with twitter bootstrap layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, primefaces

I integrated Twitter Bootstrap v2.3.1 in a Primefaces v3.5 project, 
I used Bootstrap for layout and Primefaces for components.

But I get a problem when using DataTable, it does not render well as you can see in the picture:
[image]

by using Firebug I figured out the problem, the default css of primefaces inputs get ovveridden by the Bootstrap input styles

here are the stylesheets loaded in the order:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/projet/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/projet/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.css.xhtml?ln=css" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/projet/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap-responsive.css.xhtml?ln=css" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/projet/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" />
```

as you see the theme.css get ovveridden by bootstrap.css

so is there a way to load all primefaces stylesheets after thoose of Bootstrap?
or is there any other solution to get correct rendering of Primefaces componenets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to [customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) (uncheck Forms under Base CSS) the bootstrap framework before downloading it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule for applying stylesheets.

Its all dependent on you so its not a solution to change the stylesheet order and in your case its is done with `!important` but it is good to use [Chris Coyier tells you when to use `!important`](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/), so specificity mechanism within the `CSS` cascade that aids conflict resolution somewhere can help you in this.

You can read about it at [sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity) and test yours at [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/).

Comment: thank you @sahil-popli, I was looking for a fast solution and I found one

Answer (score 1):

This post is in portuguese, but the examples are simple and you can download datatable.css, to use in your project.

http://jnaldo.com/2013/03/deixando-a-datatable-do-primefaces-com-o-tema-do-twitter-bootstrap/

Sorry for my "old celtic arabic english".